# Implementing abstract methods in Python 3

Tags: python

I am just trying to practice coding an abstract method in Python and i have the following code for it:

```
import abc
class test(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def first(self,name):
        """This is to be implemented"""

class Extendtest(test):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def first(self):
        print ("Changing name!")
        self.name = "Shaayan"

    def second(self,value):
        print ("Adding second argument!")
        self.value = value

e = Extendtest("Subhayan")
print (e.name) 
e.first()
print (e.name)
```

I intentionally changed the signature of the first method in the implementation of the abstract method.

But if i change the signature Python is not giving any error and is going through as expected.

Is there no way in Python by which i can force strict abstraction ?

Comment: In Python abstract methods are not necessary. Just use duck-typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a new question asked about python and a short answer:

No, it is not possible. The easiest way is either to reuse a custom library like [zope](http://zopeinterface.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or implement this behavior by your own.

There was a proposal on ABC to check arguments and here is what Guido answers on this:

> That is not a new idea. So far I have always rejected it because I
>   worry about both false positives and false negatives. Trying to
>   enforce that the method *behaves* as it should (or even its return
>   type) is hopeless; there can be a variety of reasons to modify the
>   argument list while still conforming to (the intent of) the interface.
>   I also worry that it will slow everything down.
>
> That said, if you want to provide a standard mechanism that can
>   *optionally* be turned on to check argument conformance, e.g. by using a class or method decorator on the subclass, I would be fine with that
>   (as long as it runs purely at class-definition time; it shouldn't slow
>   down class instantiation or method calls). It will probably even find
>   some bugs. It will also surely have to be tuned to avoid certain
>   classes false positives.

[reference to the thread](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-ideas/109qtkrzsd/abc-what-about-the-method-arguments)